# Why I get null when try get element by id?

Tags: angular, angular5

I tried to modify element in page, when template was loaded:

```
ngAfterContentInit() {
    var oldParent = document.getElementById('card-list-wrapper');
    console.log(oldParent);
    document.body.innerHTML += oldParent;
    oldParent.innerHTML = '';
  }
```

Template:

```
<div *ngIf="dataLoaded2" id="card-list-wrapper"></div>
```

But I get `console.log(oldParent);` null, why?

Comment: Can you add the relevant HTML as well please? Or better yet, create a StackBlitz that reproduces the issue

Comment: are you sure that dataLoaded2 is true ?

Comment: Yes, sure, it was loaded

Comment: It's not coming from an asynchronous process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's a good practice to avoid vanilla JS in a typescript file:

```
<div *ngIf="dataLoaded2" id="card-list-wrapper" #card></div>
```

and in ts file:

```
export class elementComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild("card", {read: ElementRef}) card: ElementRef;

    constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {}

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        console.log(this.card.nativeElement);
    }  

}
```

Comment: Elemeny #card is created by click. it means `console.log(this.card.nativeElement);` can no fin it